# failed to add div to PDF inside .each() function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am exporting the multiple div content into the PDF. I want to show each div content in separate pages when exported the data to the PDF.For this to achieve i was trying to add as shown in below code but still unable to show each div content in individual pages as shown in the demo plunker (when user click on export button, PDF is downloaded and can see div content is shown in individual pages) : https://plnkr.co/edit/KvkVlYmmmJiZ71sghb1l?p=preview (working demo plunker, it shows each div content in individual pages of the PDF).

```
      source.append($('<div>'));
      source.append($(this));
      source.append($('</div><!--ADD_PAGE-->'));
```

complete js code:

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {

    $scope.employees = [{pageIndex: "randomText1",pageHeader: "This should be shown in page1"},
    {pageIndex: "randomeTexthere",pageHeader: "This should be shown in page2"},
    {pageIndex: "someRandomText",pageHeader: "This should be shown in page3"},
    {pageIndex: "four",pageHeader: "This is shown in page4"},];

 $scope.export = function() {
   var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
   var source = $('#append-source');
    $('.myDivClass').each(function(){
      var html = $(this);
      source.append($('<div style="background-color: yellow">'));
      source.append(html));
      source.append($('</div><!--ADD_PAGE-->'));
    //var html = "<div>"+$(this) + "</div><!--ADD_PAGE-->";//the code is broken with this line

    });
    console.log(source);
    pdf.addHTML(
          source, 0, 0, {
              pagesplit: true
          },
          function(dispose){
              pdf.save('test3.pdf');
          }
      );
     }
   }
 ]);
```

Demo plunker (failed to add new div in .each()) : https://plnkr.co/edit/uUiK0Mv8mn88JEEyI3rf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your html separately to your pdf file.
Finally change your `$scope.export` function like this.

```
 $scope.export = function() {
   var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
    $('.myDivClass').each(function(){
      var html = $(this);
      pdf.fromHTML(html.html(),15,15,{'width':170});
      pdf.addPage();          
    });
     pdf.save('test3.pdf');
 }
```

UPDATE: If you are going to save using addHTML.
The of each div will be different and you can't divide the image with same height. So you have to add the div separately.
**Code**

```
   $scope.html = [];
   $scope.addPagesAndPrint = function(pdf, index){
      var source = $('#append-source');
      source.empty();

      source.append($('<div>'));
      source.append($scope.html[index]);
      source.append($('</div><!--ADD_PAGE-->'));

      pdf.addHTML(
          source, 0, 0, {
              pagesplit: true
          },
          function(dispose){
            if(index == $scope.html.length - 1)
              pdf.save('test4.pdf');
            else{
              pdf.addPage();
              $scope.addPagesAndPrint(pdf, index + 1);
            }
          }
      );
   }
   $scope.export = function() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
      $('.myDivClass').each(function(){
        $scope.html.push($(this));
      });
      $scope.addPagesAndPrint(pdf, 0);
   }
```

Comment: I cannot use pdf.fromHTML as it is not loading some special characters displayed on the webpage. Please find the sample demo with your suggested code : https://plnkr.co/edit/mb6a9M2yi0iQwL2JA0dn?p=preview, it contains some yellow color highlighted text, when exported to PDF the color is not exported,similarly i see some issues with fromHTML, that is the reason i have used addHTML instead of fromHTML.. Any suggestions with out modifying the actual logic would be helpful.

Comment: @user8838953, UPDATED answer with addHTML function.